# White lines in confusion matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, confusion-matrix

I have a pretty general question about numpy matrices : I've tried to normalized the results depending on the lines but I've getting some weird white lines. Is this because of some zeros stuck somewhere in division?

Here is the code :

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.pylab import *

def confusion_matrix(results,tagset):
    # results : list of tuples (predicted, true)
    # tagset  : list of tags
    np.seterr(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore')
    mat     = np.zeros((len(tagset),len(tagset)))
    percent = [0,0]
    for guessed,real in results :
        mat[tagset.index(guessed),tagset.index(real)] +=1
        if guessed == real :
            percent[0] += 1
            percent[1] += 1
        else :
            percent[1] += 1
    mat /=  mat.sum(axis=1)[:,np.newaxis]
    matshow(mat,fignum=100)
    xticks(arange(len(tagset)),tagset,rotation =90,size='x-small')
    yticks(arange(len(tagset)),tagset,size='x-small')
    colorbar()
    show()
    #print "\n".join(["\t".join([""]+tagset)]+["\t".join([tagset[i]]+[str(x) for x in 
                (mat[i,:])]) for i in xrange(mat.shape[1])])
    return (percent[0] / float(percent[1]))*100
```

Thanks for your time ! (I hope the answer is not too obvious)

Comment: An example image might help (what are "weird white lines"). To make debugging easy you might try to separate your code in to two parts: One that creates the matrix and one that plots the matrix. Then in ipython (or other) run the first function to get the matrix. Check that there are not zeros or NaNs in the data for an entire line and that it looks as you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a nutshell, you have some tags where that particular tag was never guessed.  Because you're normalizing by the number of times the tag was guessed, you have a row of `0/0` which yields `np.nan`.  By default, matplotlib's colorbars will set `NaN`'s to have no fill color, causing the background of the axes to show through (by default, white).

Here's a quick example to reproduce your current problem:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def main():
    tags = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
    results = [('A', 'A'), ('B', 'B'), ('C', 'C'), ('A', 'D'), ('C', 'A'),
               ('B', 'B'), ('C', 'B')]
    matrix = confusion_matrix(results, tags)
    plot(matrix, tags)
    plt.show()

def confusion_matrix(results, tagset):
    output = np.zeros((len(tagset), len(tagset)), dtype=float)
    for guessed, real in results:
        output[tagset.index(guessed), tagset.index(real)] += 1
    return output / output.sum(axis=1)[:, None]

def plot(matrix, tags):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    im = ax.matshow(matrix)
    cb = fig.colorbar(im)
    cb.set_label('Percentage Correct')

    ticks = range(len(tags))
    ax.set(xlabel='True Label', ylabel='Predicted Label',
           xticks=ticks, xticklabels=tags, yticks=ticks, yticklabels=tags)
    ax.xaxis.set(label_position='top')
    return fig

main()
```

[image]

And if we take a look at the confusion matrix:

```
array([[ 0.5  ,  0.   ,  0.   ,  0.5  ],
       [ 0.   ,  1.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ],
       [ 0.333,  0.333,  0.333,  0.   ],
       [   nan,    nan,    nan,    nan]])
```

If you'd like to avoid the problems when a tag is never guessed, you could do something similar to:

```
def confusion_matrix(results, tagset):
    output = np.zeros((len(tagset), len(tagset)), dtype=float)
    for guessed, real in results:
        output[tagset.index(guessed), tagset.index(real)] += 1
    num_guessed = output.sum(axis=1)[:, None]
    num_guessed[num_guessed == 0] = 1
    return output / num_guessed
```

Which yields (with everything else identical):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not directly answering your question but this is very easy to do with [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html):

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y_test=[2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1]
y_pred = [2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 2]

cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
print(cm)

# Plot confusion matrix
plt.matshow(cm)
plt.title('Confusion matrix')
plt.colorbar()    plt.ylabel('True label')
plt.xlabel('Predicted label')
plt.show()
```

**Output:**

```
[[13  0  0]
 [ 0 15  1]
 [ 0  0  9]]
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, OK. Thanks a lot. Well, mine works if I skip the normalization part... So if I want to normalize the matrix with your code, I need to do it before (in the lists), right ? I'm going to check scikit but I wanted to implement it myself...